# How can I store the value of 'series' as a session variable?

Tags: javascript, php

### Heading

how i get the selected value of city_id from drop down list and store in a session??

`

```html
<form action="dynamic.php" method="post">
<select name="city" > 
<option value="">Select City</option>
 <?php
 $sql="select * from city ORDER BY city_name";
 $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row["city_id"];?>"><?php echo $row["city_name"];?></option>
  <?php
 }    
 ?>
</select>



</form>
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['city'])){
    $_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city'];
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: You submit the form towards `dynamic.php` as you've set it up and there you do something like `$_SESSION['city_id'] = $_POST['city'];`

Comment: @SterlingArcher I wouldn't call that a duplicate. He's asking how to store the value into a session. Not how to get the value with JS.

Comment: <?php
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_POST['city'])){
        $_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city'];
    }
 ?>
i did it  but not working

Comment: Please clerify _"it's not working"_. How did you test it? Did you call `session_start();` on the page where you are getting the session value as well? Otherwise the session will be lost.

Comment: yes i start session ..but not working ...giving an error like  Undefined index: city_id in ...

Comment: @Manich you could try using `isset` instead of `!empty` and this should not produce the undefined index error.
Like this:


    if (isset($_POST['city_id'])) {
        $_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city'];
    }

Comment: @zysoft That's not correct. `isset()` does exactly the same as `empty()` except that `empty()` also verifies if the variable has a value or not. - Manich: What I don't get is that you're getting an error _Undefined index: city_id_ while your code doesn't have any array with `city_id` in it? All I see is indexes with `city`.

Comment: @icecub You are right. I think the problem is in `<option value="<?php echo $row["city_id"];?>">` and the script stops before it could save the value in session. Without database structure its hard to guess further. Anyway it's the only place I see `city_id` in the code.

Comment: @zysoft Yup. The problem is most likely the MySQL connection, query and/or database structure. OP should do some proper error handling on those. Nice find.

Comment: @icecub:previously I use $_SESSION['city_id']  then i change it into to  $_SESSION['city']  ,that's why show udefined index:city_id

Comment: @Manich Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50476296/edit) your question and include the code where you're verifying the session variable.

Comment: @icecub thanxx ..its working now...

Comment: @icecub: i have a query... if i use button in <form> tag it not direct the target page ?..<button href="dynamic.php">mani</button>//can you explain ...

Comment: You submit a form with `<form action="dynamic.php"><input type="submit" value="Submit form"/></form>`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to session_start();

Then

$_SESSION['city'] = 'somecity';

Answer (score 0):

you need use this in each page that you use the var:

```
session_start();
```

then you can add this

```
$_SESSION["myvar"] = "something"
```